# The text from UITextField is disappear in UITableView,If scroll the UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a problem on UITableView,If i placed UITextField in UITableView,the entered text in UITextField is deleted,if scroll the UITableView. Any way to keep that data in UITextField.

I have used the below code

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cell_ID=@"CELL_ID";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_ID];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        if([nib count]>0)
        {
            cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load nib");
        }
    }

    UITextField *txt1=(UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];//not needed

    return cell;

}
```

I have designed the `UITableViewCell` using the xib

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to use input data in uitextfields in which are in tableview. Then you should reload your tableview. After entering data

Comment: i have entered data in UITextField dynamically,

Comment: Can you show your cell forrowatindexpathmethod?

Comment: Please show the code which your using.

Comment: I have include the code,now-please check it now-I have design the UITableViewCell using the xib

Answer (score 0):

Un check the auto resize subvies in table view xib file.
and set editable no to the textfiled